# Degrees of freedom for t-distribution in hypothesis test

Tags: distributions, self-study, t-distribution

I am currently doing a True/False exercise. One of the questions as follows:

> A marine drill instructor recoded the time in which each of 20 recruits completed an obstacle course both before and after training. To test whether any improvement occurred, the instructor would use a t-distribution with 38 degrees of freedom.

While this statement is obviously **False** due to the fact that the degree-of-freedom cannot be 38 since there are only 20 recruits, I was wondering if the following statements will make the statement true:

- degree of freedom should be 19
- it is assumed that a population standard deviation is not available, hence the use of the t-distribution

Appreciate any advice please.

Comment: If you did a two-sample t test, you would have 38 df, since there are 40 measurements and two means are estimated. The most critical thing to understand is why it *isn't* a two-sample test.

Comment: @Glen_b Hi Glen, since time has passed and I am also curious, would you mind elaborating why a two sample-test is not appropriate? Thank you.

Comment: @JohnK You're right, it should be clarified. The point was that the data are paired (before-after on each person); the OP seems to have realized this but to my mind didn't clearly articulate what the issue was. A paired t-test is merely a one sample test on the differences; the intent of my comment was to distinguish it from an unpaired test, which is what people mean when they say 'two-sample t-test' without further adjectives. Most of the OP's reasoning was correct, but needed to hone in on what I think is central to clearly stating what's happening there.

Comment: The question is ambiguous because the instructor perfectly well *could* use a two-sample t-test (having, therefore, 38 degrees of freedom). The problem statement does not say whether the instructor kept track of each recruit's times individually or only recorded the two sets of 20 times. In the latter case a paired t-test would be impossible, but a two-sample t-test could be justified by the assumption that the recruits' times were not negatively correlated, implying that if it rejected the null, then so would the two-sample test (if it could have been performed).

Answer (score 1):

You have the right answer, but I want to make sure you understand why.  Notice that you have two measurements per recruit for a total of 40 measurements.  Can you explain why it would be inappropriate to perform a two-sample t-test with 38 degrees of freedom?